# OTA upgrade after flashing with stock Lollipop ROM

Tags: custom-roms, htc-one, 5.1-lollipop, stock-rom

I flashed my HTC One M8 with a stock Lollipop ROM from [here](http://graffixnyc.com/m8.php#rom).

And now there's an OTA upgrade available called Android L-MR1 that I cannot install because when the phone reboots it boots into TeamWin recovery mode and requires a password.

The password is most likely because the phone is encrypted, but typing in my lock screen code is invalid.

I ask TeamWin to reboot into system and the story begins from square 1 with the upgrade being ready to install.

So how do I proceed to get this upgrade installed? Should I remove TeamWin recovery?